# What is the best way to store data that is depend on days?

Tags: sql, database-design

What is the best way to store this data:

**The Problem:**
**Let say I have Stores table, and the day they open.**

Store A open on Sunday, Wednesday

Store B open every day

Store C open on Thursday, Friday

etc

I have some solution like:

1. Make 2 tables, Store Table and WorkingDay Table
2. Make 1 Store table that contains 7 days column(Sunday, Monday, ...), and set it to true if they open
3. Make 1 table and add 1 column that saves the day they open as json.

**Please note that:**

1. I don't need the hour, I just need the day.
2. I will make query to get all Store that opens on Sunday, or Monday, etc

**My question is:
What is the best way to store this data? Or if you have another solution will be appreciate**

Thank you

Comment: The "best" way depends on how the data is going to be used and modified.  I also removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: How I use the data is I will query the data like what stores open on Sundays, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you don't need the hour, and assuming what you're trying to optimize is **read performance**, and an elegant schema: I would recommend 7 additional columns for each store, type "bit" with a filtered index on each column.

Depending on the page size of the store table and how often you query for business days, you likely will want to have stores and business days in two seperate tables.

```
CREATE TABLE store (id INT PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE businessDays (
  store_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES store(id),
  sunday bit DEFAULT 0, 
  monday bit DEFAULT 0,
  tuesday bit DEFAULT 0,
  wednesday bit DEFAULT 0,
  thursday bit DEFAULT 0,
  friday bit DEFAULT 0,
  saturday bit DEFAULT 0,
  INDEX ix_sunday (sunday) WHERE sunday = 1,
  INDEX ix_monday (monday) WHERE monday = 1,
  INDEX ix_tuesday (tuesday) WHERE tuesday = 1,
  INDEX ix_wednesday (wednesday) WHERE wednesday = 1,
  INDEX ix_thursday (thursday) WHERE thursday = 1,
  INDEX ix_friday (friday) WHERE friday = 1,
  INDEX ix_saturday (saturday) WHERE saturday = 1)
```

I hope this helps! Don't hesitate if you have further questions. :-)